# What short SF story has these words

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The wall at the edge of the World.  A lift to go the final few steps. Many years ago. the Wall had no other side.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Comment: At least 20 years ago.

Comment: I found it:"Wall of Darkness" Arthur Clark

Comment: You should post that as an answer; answers will show up in searches where comments may not.